# How could you split number string by the value of them?

Tags: python, split, digits, continuous

I have a number string like below.

s = "1123433364433"

I'd like to get the result list of splited continuous same value like this.
You can't change the location of the original each digit.

result = ["11", "2", "3", "4", "333", "6", "44", "33"]

What should be the easiest way to get this?

Answer (score 6):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
s = "1123433364433"
print([''.join(i) for _, i in groupby(s)])
```

This outputs:

```
['11', '2', '3', '4', '333', '6', '44', '33']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use module `re` for that as well:

```
import re
s = "1123433364433"
print([v[0] for v in re.finditer(r'(.)\1*', s)])
```

Outputs:

```
['11', '2', '3', '4', '333', '6', '44', '33']
```